# Button width property ignored?

Tags: html, css, button

Both Firefox and Safari don't seem to properly render a button specified with a certain width:

```
<form>
<button>foo</button><br>
<button style="width=200px;height:200px">baz</button>
</form>
```

Button baz will render with specified height but default width. Same result in both Firefox and Safari.

Is this by design? How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a syntax error:

```
<button style="width=200px;height:200px">baz</button>
```

Should be:

```
<button style="width:200px;height:200px">baz</button>
```

Comment: it works inline but how can i make it work with css file

Comment: @Sumon: why wouldn't it work in the CSS file? This solution was posted as a syntax correction; if your css isn't applying then it's either syntax or specificity. Which do you think it is?